# account merge gone bad

Tags: support, merge-accounts

Accidentally I've created two different accounts in the network: one with my main google openid and one with reserve one for some reason. The main account (with reserve openid) was pseudonymous but second (with main openid) had my full name stated. I needed to enter full name for Area 51, so I decided to associate my main openid with my main account. Things became very messy (see last paragraph). Here's the link to my account https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/7846/dmytro-korduban You can see strange dates in "recent names". Could you please rollback the changes and merge manually, if it's not too late? Thank you in advance.

Upd: My flag actions at cstheory are gone (with corresponding badge) and if you look at the all account stats from [meta profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178942/dmytro-korduban), it states that I haven't any reputation at cstheory (but I still have badges). Looks like bug.

Comment: I've earned 1 badge back, but 1 is still missing and there are still +2 extra reputation...

Comment: Does a manual repuation recalc with the button at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation help?

Comment: Well no, but at least I've understood the reason of +2 (suggested edit accepted today). Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Associating one OpenID with two accounts is actually [the proper way to trigger an automatic merge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist).

Doing this "manually" would have the same results, so there's no point in trying to roll it back now.

Some things will always look a bit odd - recent names, for instance - because they're drawn from the union of two separate timelines.

Others - the reputation displayed for associated accounts - will resolve themselves over time as caches get rebuilt.

Finally, you can set your display name for each site individually - it doesn't need to be the same on all sites across the network. So if you want to be Dmytro on one site, and dkoruban on another, just change your name separately in both places.

---

After consultation with the developers, it appears that flag history is lost when merging (or rather, the flag history isn't *merged* - whichever account "wins" in the merge keeps its history, and the other is discarded).

Comment: There was 2 different OpenIDs and some stuff still looks broken (badges, flag history etc).

Comment: Thank you, that explains things.